# how to access custom exception handler from python module?

Tags: python, exception

These are my files:

```
myModule/__init__.py

import sys

class MyModule:
  handle_exceptions = handle_exceptions
  def __init__(self):
    sys.excepthook = handle_exceptions

#myModule/handle_exceptions.py
def handle_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
  #not important here      
  pass


#my_script.py
import sys
import myModule
sys.excepthook = myModule.handle_exceptions
```

The contents of 'handle_exceptions' is not important here because I can't access it at all.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "my_script.py", line 2, in <module>
    import myModule
 File "D:\Python34\myModule\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    class MyModule:
 File "D:\Python34\myModule\__init__.py", line 4, in MyModule
    handle_exceptions = handle_exceptions
 NameError: name 'handle_exceptions' is not defined
```

Comment: you should have a member handle_exceptions in mymodule. self.handle_exceptions = handle_exceptions

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana: updated question with your suggestion, same thing.

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana: updated question, again it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry what ever you had initially is correct only thing you have to do is while importing import the method from myModule import handle_exception and then you can assign to sys.excepthook = handle_exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myModule/__init__.py
import sys

class MyModule:
  def __init__(self):
    sys.excepthook = handle_exceptions
    self.handle_exceptions = handle_exceptions


#myModule/handle_exceptions.py
def handle_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
  #not important here
  pass




import sys
from myModule import handle_exceptions
sys.excepthook = handle_exceptions
```